# How to create a copper pad for heat dissipation in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, heat, thermal, power-dissipation, pad

[image]

The data sheet for this component, the RPX-1.0, says

> SW Switch node. Connect 6, 7, and 8 to large copper pad for optimal heat dissipation.

Is a "large copper pad" an extra component that you solder onto the PCB and then solder the pins to that pad?

Or when creating your layout do create a pad somehow that those pins connect to?

Comment: The copper pad in this case would be a copper plane or polygon you make when doing the board layout.  It isn't part of the footprint.

Comment: It’s at least 5 to 10 cm^2 of Cu or Alumclad per watt &  do the match on max ambient temp and 85’C junction temp